# Unexpected JSON behavior

Tags: javascript, php, json, wordpress

I'm building a WordPress plugin. The PHP script sends the JSON, javascript receives it. Time to time, the js receives an empty JSON, even when I'm sure it should receive data. If I put an empty echo `(echo ' ';)`, it fixes my problem and the data received correctly.
The receiver:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: url + "get_bookings.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            week: t,
            year: e
        }
    }).done(function(w) {
         w = JSON.parse(w);
        fetchTableData(w)
    })
```

The sender:

```
echo ' ';
.
. // Code here.
echo json_encode( $query );
```

I couldn't find why this happens. Sometimes it works fine without the empty `echo`.

Edit: thanks for the answers, the `exit` did not help.
I checked the network panel, and it was requesting get_bookings.php twice. I put a slash at the end of the URL, and works fine.

```
url: url + "get_bookings.php/",
```

Comment: '*even when I am sure it should receive data*' - How sure are you? Could the query be returning nothing? Have you got a check for that? Check the documentation for the second parameter of `json_encode`.

Comment: Because I know when it should receive data, and it is receiving when I put the echo ' '; on top.

Comment: Please give more context about the “sender” part. Are you properly stopping any further script execution after that?

Comment: its usually good to put an `exit` after the `json_encode(...)` part.

Comment: technically it should work or not work at all. Have you monitored the ajax request in the network panel of your browser console?

Answer (score 1):

First, remove this line:

```
echo ' ';
```

Id suggest debugging the PHP script first by testing the resulting value for `$query`:

```
print_r($query);
```

If the value intermittently results as an empty string, then make sure to test for this and return an empty JSON object instead when necessary.

```
if (empty($query)) {
  $query = (Object)[];
}
echo json_encode($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the second parameter true in json_encode and also issue is header already sent error.
You don't need header for json encode in ajax return. just add json_encode and that's it.

Comment: I tried to do it with and without header, and the second parameter of json_encode. If I remove the empty echo,  I get an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input